# setState() rerendering of particular Widget. Need code fix

Tags: dart, flutter

**Hi,**

Below code example is taken from when we create a new project in flutter.

**Question:**

`_MyHomePageState` will rerender as soon as `_incrementCounter` is pressed. This will rerender appBar, body, and FloatingActionButton (build method which is costly). Am I right? If right, the only thing that should rerender is a body with text.
How can I separate Widgets that needs re-rendering only? Means separating Stateless and Stateful in the below code. I hope you get my point?

Thanks

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Hot reload'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            new Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS36gBEp8OI explains exactly that example.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter will determine which Widgets need to be recreated or rebuilt, and only recreate / rebuild those.

IIRC, on each setState() (or animation tick, or other re-render), Flutter traverses the Widget tree and compares the before and after state of each Widget tree branch. A stateful widget is only rebuilt if its state has actually changed, and only changed stateless Widgets will be recreated. So in your case, _MyHomePageState is rebuilt, but only the second Text widget is recreated.

See 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkyY9WCGMi0&t=171s
for a far more detailed explanation of Widgets (and underlying elements and render boxes).

Comment: You mean _MyHomePageState -> build method will rerender but it will rerender only Text widget? Youtube video link provided by Günter Zöchbauer in the above comment shows how to tackle the rerendering of a particular widget with Inherited Widget, redux or streams. What is that then?